# How to run SVC classifier after running 10-fold cross validation in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, cross-validation

I'm relatively new to machine learning and would like some help in the following:

I ran a Support Vector Machine Classifier (SVC) on my data with 10-fold cross validation and calculated the accuracy score (which was around 89%). I'm using Python and scikit-learn to perform the task. Here's a code snippet:

```
def get_scores(features,target,classifier):
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(features, target , 
    test_size=0.3)
    scores = cross_val_score(
    classifier,
    X_train,
    y_train,
    cv=10,
    scoring='accuracy',
    n_jobs=-1)
 return(scores)

get_scores(features_from_df,target_from_df,svm.SVC())
```

Now, how can I use my classifier (after running the 10-folds cv) to test it on X_test and compare the predicted results to y_test? As you may have noticed, I only used X_train and y_train in the cross validation process.

I noticed that sklearn have cross_val_predict: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html should I replace my cross_val_score by cross_val_predict? just FYI: my target data column is binarized (have values of 0s and 1s).

If my approach is wrong, please advise me with the best way to proceed with.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
# Build your classifier
classifier = svm.SVC()

# Train it on the entire training data set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Get predictions on the test set
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

At this point, you can use any metric from the [`sklearn.metrics`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) module to determine how well you did. For example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. This, however, doesn't take cross-validation into consideration. Any alternative suggestions would be great.

Comment: @M_13 No model will ever take cross-validation into account. CV is just to check the performance of the model on your data. Please read about [cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Comment: I wonder how this answer is accpeted as an 'answer'. It doesn't address the main point which is cross-validation

Answer (score 14):

You only need to split your X and y. Do not split the train and test.

Then you can pass your classifier in your case svm to the `cross_val_score` function to get the accuracy for each experiment.

In just 3 lines of code:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10)
print scores
```

Comment: And don't forget: ```from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score```

Answer (score -2):

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
classifier = svm.SVC()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test , y_pred)
```